# Using Regex Anchors in an OR class?

Tags: regex

Lets say I am looking for the word `test` in a comma delimited list. The word `test` can be at the start of a string, in the middle of the string, or at the end of the string. So assuming I have series of rows including the following:

```
 this,test,should,match
 test,should,match
 should,match,test
 this,ttest,should,not,match
```

Notice that the 4th line contains `ttest` not `test` and I don't want it to match. Is there a regular expression I could do that would match the first 3 lines, but not the fourth? I have it started with this:

```
[,]test[,]
```

This of course, would match line 1, and not 4, but would not match 2 and 3, because it wouldn't match the beginning of a line, or the end of the line. Is there a way to add beginning and end anchors to the `[,]` character class in order to get them included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not indicated what regex engine you're using, so it's impossible to answer definitively; but many engines support the notation `foo|bar` for alternation, and the notation `(foo)` for grouping, so you can very likely write:

```
(^|,)test(,|$)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I was trying to do it with the `[fo]` character class, and that doesn't support line boundaries. In PCRE however, wouldn't `(foo)` be a callback class?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod: I'm not sure what you mean by "callback class". If you mean that it would perform capture as well as grouping (so that you can refer back to the matched substring), then -- yes. You could avoid that by writing `(?:foo)` instead. I went with `(foo)` because it works in a greater variety of regex engines. (In the future, please keep in mind that a question should never have *only* the 'regex' tag, because 'regex' can mean many different things. You should always make clear what kind of regex you need.)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not *have* to use an or-clause, and assuming only one word is in each group, an alternative is

```
\btest\b
```

Answer (score 0):

ruakh's answer addresses your question directly, however a simpler solution would be to use word boundaries instead of looking for anchors and commas:

`\btest\b`

Comment: Oooh... I never knew about word boundaries. However, I don't think this would work, because it would also match dashes and underscores, and I need this to only match commas and line boundaries.

Comment: Your data has nothing but letters. You gotta put all information into your question, or we're going to give you answers that don't work, right?  ;)